# If an unfair coin flipped 8 times. What is the probability of flipping 6 heads with the first and last flip being heads?

Tags: statistics, probability

If an unfair coin is flipped with 8 times with P(H) = .60. What is the probability of flipping 6 heads with the first and last flip being heads?

HW question in Coursera probability and statistics course

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

should be p(h)*p(h) = 0.36 since you don't care about the results in the middle.